# Date conversion YYYYMMDD to YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have a date string in format YYYYMMDD for example 20140330 
In xsl 1.0 I want to convert the date string to format YYYY-MM-DD for example 2014-03-30

I tried using several date functions but it did not work.
Can anyone help me to convert the date ?

Comment: XSLT 1.0 doesn't have any "date functions" (the date-related functions are part of XPath 2.0), you will have to use plain string manipulation.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I now upgraded my software to use xpath 2 and I tried using function xp20:format-dateTime('19711018','[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]') but the function is not returning any value.. I am expecting 1971-10-18... not sure if I am missing something!!

Comment: "*I now upgraded my software to use xpath 2*"  Post a new question, then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the substring function. Given the following input XML:

```
<root>20140330</root>
```

and the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(., 1, 4), '-', substring(., 5, 2), '-', substring(., 7, 2))"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

it outputs:

```
2014-03-30
```

Comment: Thank you. It works . Now I am trying to use xpath function. I now upgraded my software to use xpath 2 and I tried using function xp20:format-dateTime('19711018','[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]') but the function is not returning any value.. I am expecting 1971-10-18... not sure if I am missing something!!

Comment: @jayak - `format-dateTime()` is an XSLT 2.0 function; not XPath. The first argument must be an `xs:dateTime`. You're trying to format a date, not a dateTime. You should use `format-date()` instead. However, the first argument for `format-date()` is an `xs:date`. The string `19711018` cannot be cast to an xs:date. You'd have to use `format-date(xs:date('1971-10-18'),'[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]')` which would return `1971-10-18` anyway. Might as well stick with the string manipulation only. (Since you're using 2.0 now you could do it this way: `replace('19711018','(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})','$1-$2-$3')`.)